# What is the correct term for crunching long words in software?

Tags: display, terminology

When drawing graphs in one of my software packages (KNIME), long text is "crunched" to fit into limited on-screen space, for example:

```
BROWN RAT becomes BRO...
SWALLOW becomes SWA...
```

and so on. I've also seen long text get crunched as follows:

```
THIS IS LONG TEXT becomes THI..XT
CHICKEN TIKKA MASALA becomes CHI..LA
```

I've seen this in lots of software. Is there a standard technical term for this feature?

Answer (score 2):

To do this to text is called truncation. It is very useful at times to be able to truncate text.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a different way of referring to `ABC...` and `ABC..YZ` truncations?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i believe this....xt would be truncate middle. I mainly use truncate when using Smarty so maybe this will be useful to you http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl